# How do you use "i.e." in a sentence?

Tags: abbreviations

How does one properly use *i.e.* in a sentence? 
I'm not referring to Internet Explorer.

Comment: There are some good answers below, but you also might want to consider not using it and writing "that is" instead.  It's just confusing otherwise.

Comment: Ah I thought IE as in Internet Explorer

Comment: @Midhat ha! Based on what I learned below, you could say that as "Ah I thought IE i.e. Internet Explorer"  :-)

Comment: Consider changing the title to say "id est" or "i.e." It'll minimize the confusion a bit.

Comment: "My browser, IE, has crashed 25 times today."

Comment: My browser is IE, i.e. I don't know of Firefox.

Comment: "My browser, i.e. IE, has crashed 25 times today." =).

Comment: You wouldn’t; you’d just say ‘that is’ or ‘meaning’ or some such. Stupid Latin abbreviations like that are silly in English. You get people pronouncing initialisms that way. Just use English.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I assume you are referring to the common abbreviation for the Latin *id est*, which is commonly translated as "that is to say".  So, think of the English when you would use it, i.e. when you're about to write *i.e.* think to yourself "that is to say".

See how I did that?  As to the stylistic issue, I would always do it as I did above: lower case, periods in place.  A common variant is *ie.* instead of *i.e.*.

Contrast with *e.g.* which is from the Latin *exempli gratia* meaning "for example."  One can construct sentences where either one is acceptable, but usually just contemplating the English meaning of each and picking the best fit is the way to go.

If you're referring to Internet Explorer, just say Internet Explorer.

Comment: Or "Infernal Exploder".

Answer (score 28):

via http://theoatmeal.com/comics/ie

> Ever done this?
>
> *"When eating a squirrel taco, Bigfoot always adds extra condiments, i.e., ranch dressing"*
>
> This is wrong!
>
> I.e. is an abbreviation of a latin phrase meaning "that is." **It's not used for listing examples; it's used for clarifying a statement.** Think of it  as "in essence" or "in other words." By using it above we're declaring that ranch dressing is the only condiment in existence, which is false.
>
> In the previous example, we should have used e.g., which means "for example."
>
> For example:
>
> *"The best way to take out a unicorn is with a Claymore, i.e., a directional mine which explodes shrapnel into a designated kill zone."*
>
> Another example:
>
> *"Eating a squirrel taco without any ranch dressing is like playing leapfrog with a unicorn, i.e. a very bad idea."*

[image]

Comment: argh you beat me to it!
full link here: http://theoatmeal.com/comics/ie

Comment: Hah. Nice comic there... though it does sort of ruin the readability of the page.

Comment: I couldn't resist... I thought the reference to unicorns was quite funny.

Comment: reformatted for plain text searchability and readability

Comment: You may want to add that "i.e." stands for "id est", which means "that is".

Comment: so 'i.e.' can't be used instead of 'in other words'? as i agree that for examples we have 'e.g.' for examples and 'viz.' for a complete list of examples i.e. there is nothing that can be added to it

Comment: "i.e., ranch dressing" is a perfectly appropriate turn of phrase.  It means something very specific, though.  It's like you're making fun of bigfoot because he always puts ranch dressing and no other condiments on all his food.

Comment: @Brad well yea, if you're *purposely* trying to be sarcastic, it might work :)

Answer (score 4):

*i.e.* is an abbreviation for the Latin "id est", meaning "that is" (or more loosely, "in other words"). Its English usage follows precisely as such. The abbreviation is simply used to signal that the following phrase is another way of expressing the preceding phrase.

(Note: *i.e.* is often misused to indicate an example; this is incorrect. Always use *e.g.* in that case.)

Comment: "It's English usage"?????

Comment: Me fail English? That's unpossible!

Comment: @Shinto: Oops, typo! 'Twas late.

Answer (score 4):

If you're referring to Internet Explorer, depending on the context you may have to indicate that it stands for that.

If you're referring to *id est*, i.e. "i.e.", [The Oatmeal has just published a comic on that](http://theoatmeal.com/comics/ie).

In all seriousness though, you use it to mean 'that is' or 'in other words' or 'in essence'. When you're explaining something, you use *i.e.* or its synonymous English phrases when you are about to express the explanation in different terms, as a means of clarity for instance.